# Want to use grep to get dataframe names from environment and then stack the rows with rbind function in R

Tags: r, rbind

I have thousands of dataframes and want to grep their names into a character vector. Then use the vector to complete the rbind function. Any suggestions?

```
dat1lkq6 <- data.frame(color = c('COLOR: RED', 'COLOR: RED', 'COLOR: BLUE', 'COLOR: GREEN', 'COLOR: BLUE'))
dat1ah2 <- data.frame(style = c('SPORTY', 'HYBRID', 'FORMAL', 'CASUAL', 'CASUAL'))
dat29fg <- data.frame(color = c('COLOR: RED', 'COLOR: CYAN', 'COLOR: BLUE', 'COLOR: RED', 'COLOR: BLUE'))
dat2xl <- data.frame(color = c('COLOR: RED', 'COLOR: CYAN', 'COLOR: BLUE', 'COLOR: RED', 'COLOR: BLUE'))
dat3g49 <- data.frame(color = c('COLOR: PURPLE', 'COLOR: RED', 'COLOR: BLUE', 'COLOR: GREEN', 'COLOR: BLUE'))
skus4 <- data.frame(sku = c('SKU: 1849354', 'SKU: 392856', 'SKU: 921385', 'SKU: 6395474', 'SKU: 8532449', 'SKU: 0285468', 'SKU: 2948327'))

#grep to get only "dat" dataframe names
all_dat_df <- base::ls(all.names = TRUE)[base::grep("^dat", base::ls(all.names = TRUE))]

#want to stack all the "dat" df's into one df, but not working
#result dataframe should have 25 rows
rbind(all_dat_df)

#tried various incarnations of dput, gsub, paste, noquote to no success
```

Comment: `dat1ah2` doesn’t have the same column as the other `dat*` dataframes. Is this intentional, and how do you want to handle this?

Comment: Yes that was intentional and doesn't affect the overall solving of the situation. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you use the grep() function to get the names of all objects that holds a data.frame, as you are already doing:

```r
all_objects <- base::ls()
all_dat_df <- all_objects[base::grep("^dat", all_objects)]
```

Now, the `all_dat_df` object is a character vector that holds a list of object names. But these are just the names of the objects, it has no reference to "where" this object lives, "what" values it holds, etc.

So you need to transform these names, into actual references to the objects/data.frames you want to combine. To do that, you ask R to collect these objects into a list with the `lapply()` function.

The `lapply()` function will apply the `get()` function to each object name in `all_dat_df`. This `get()` function will get the actual reference of the object that you are referencing with the object name. `lapply()` will just store the results of `get()` inside a R list.

```r
list_of_data_frames <- lapply(all_dat_df, get, envir = globalenv())
```

After that, you just need to apply the `dplyr::bind_rows()` function over the list of data.frames you collected:

```r
big_data_frame <- dplyr::bind_rows(list_of_data_frames)
```

Now, the `big_data_frame` object holds a single data.frame that have all rows from all data.frames found at your global environment by `grep()`.

**NOTE:** In order to use the `dplyr::bind_rows()` function, you need to have the `dplyr` package installed in your machine. If you do not have this package installed, use the code below to install it:

```r
install.packages("dplyr")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep()` with `value = TRUE` to get matching object names. Then use `mget()` to get a list of associated dataframes from the environment. Finally, you can use `dplyr::bind_rows()` or possibly `do.call(rbind)` to combine into one.

```
library(dplyr)

grep("^dat", ls(), value = TRUE) |>
  mget() |>
  bind_rows()
```

```
    style         color
1  SPORTY          <NA>
2  HYBRID          <NA>
3  FORMAL          <NA>
4  CASUAL          <NA>
5  CASUAL          <NA>
6    <NA>    COLOR: RED
7    <NA>    COLOR: RED
8    <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
9    <NA>  COLOR: GREEN
10   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
11   <NA>    COLOR: RED
12   <NA>   COLOR: CYAN
13   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
14   <NA>    COLOR: RED
15   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
16   <NA>    COLOR: RED
17   <NA>   COLOR: CYAN
18   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
19   <NA>    COLOR: RED
20   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
21   <NA> COLOR: PURPLE
22   <NA>    COLOR: RED
23   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
24   <NA>  COLOR: GREEN
25   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
```

I used `dplyr::bind_rows()` because it handles cases where column names differ across dataframes, as in your example data. If columns *don’t* differ and you prefer a base R solution, you could use `do.call(rbind)`.

```
grep("^dat", ls(), value = TRUE) |>
  mget() |>
  do.call(what = rbind)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `pattern` in `ls` to `^dat` to get only those starting with `dat`.

```
all_dat_df <- ls(pattern = "^dat")
all_dat_df
#[1] "dat1ah2"  "dat1lkq6" "dat29fg"  "dat2xl"   "dat3g49"

#do.call(rbind, mget(all_dat_df)) #Does not work, as the named are not the same
do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, mget(all_dat_df))
#    style         color
#1  SPORTY          <NA>
#2  HYBRID          <NA>
#3  FORMAL          <NA>
#4  CASUAL          <NA>
#5  CASUAL          <NA>
#6    <NA>    COLOR: RED
#7    <NA>    COLOR: RED
#8    <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
#9    <NA>  COLOR: GREEN
#10   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
#11   <NA>    COLOR: RED
#12   <NA>   COLOR: CYAN
#13   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
#14   <NA>    COLOR: RED
#15   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
#16   <NA>    COLOR: RED
#17   <NA>   COLOR: CYAN
#18   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
#19   <NA>    COLOR: RED
#20   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
#21   <NA> COLOR: PURPLE
#22   <NA>    COLOR: RED
#23   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
#24   <NA>  COLOR: GREEN
#25   <NA>   COLOR: BLUE
```

Comment: Nice idea. Clever.